# Переход с MS Visual 6 на  Visual 9

Tags: visual-studio, c++

В C++ ещё новичок! Только-только от Delphi на С++ перешёл. И такая проблема:
В Visual 2008, когда создаю MFC программу, не могу найти компоненты, которые я видел в Visual 6, т. е. ничего не получается, т. к. даже button найти не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Откройте ToolBox(Ctrl+Alt+X) при наведении на компонент, будет подсказка что это и для чего это.